# transparency of widgets in gtkoverlay

Tags: gtk, overlay, alpha

i am trying to place several elements with gtkoverlay: 3 images and 3 labels, they should overlap. everything works pretty fine, i can place them nicely but the transparency is not used, i've tried svg and png for the images and the labels print with the bounding box in white. anyone could help me to understand what is happening or guide me to force the reading of the transparency channel?
maybe 
GTKOVERLAY_background_disable (true)...
if it exist

Comment: I have seen the same issue, but I haven't resolved it. Have you found a way to resolve this?

Comment: Here is some code that I wrote that has two PNGs, a GtkDrawingArea and a GtkLabel inside an overlay. The transparency works on the PC that I wrote this on, but I will need to check how it works for the system I am trying to debug. Please let me know if there is anything missing that could cause transparency to break on certain systems. https://github.com/sweckhoff/GTK-Cairo-Sinusoids/blob/master/gtk_cairo_sinusoid_plot.c